# I need to limit this query to 1000 records and display the count() in the TOTAL field, how can I do this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to limit the following query to 1000 records and have that number show in the TOTAL column. I can not use fetch as that command occurs after TOTAL is calculated. Is this possible here?

```
SELECT M.SEQ_NBR,
COUNT(*) OVER() TOTAL, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ_NBR DESC) ROWNUMBER 
FROM MYTABLE M 
ORDER BY ROWNUMBER;
```

I need line 2 to be something like below, but get 
"ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 1000 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 1000 END OVER() TOTAL,
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for..

```
select y.*, case when total > 1000 then 1000 else total end total_revamped from 
     (select x.*,row_number() over (order by null) rownumber,count(1) over () total 
      from all_source x where 1=1) y
where rownumber <= 1000
order by rownumber
OFFSET 995 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

You can replace the table/columns as per your need. Getting the required result in 1 query is quite impossible as you need to first evaluate the records in said table. This is the reason we need to wrap the query into an inner query which does the evaluation for you.

Comment: Thank you! 
Should my normal WHERE clause (excluding the rownumber check above) be in the nested query? 

I also use OFFSET and FETCH NEXT for paging, and have that in the outer query, is that correct?

Comment: @devo00 Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to limit a number of rows to 1000:

```
SELECT M.SEQ_NBR,
       COUNT(*) OVER() TOTAL, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ_NBR DESC) ROWNUMBER 
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE rownum <= 1000
) M 
ORDER BY ROWNUMBER;
```

Comment: This won't (necessarily) return the first 1000 rows according to the SEQ_NBR  order, if that is important. If you just want _any_ 1000 rows, then this will do. A solution to that would be to do the sorting in the subquery, and move the where clause to the main query. It might be slower then, because the whole set needs to be sorted, but if you want to dictate which rows you'll get, that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have just connected the dots from your question.

Did not able to understand the issue properly, But I tried following to help you out. -- I have used only 10 rows, You can replace it with 1000.

```
SELECT
    SEQ_NBR,
    COUNT(*) OVER() TOTAL
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            M.SEQ_NBR
        FROM
            MYTABLE M
        ORDER BY
            SEQ_NBR DESC
        FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
    );
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2631677e7cfb6bcdc9d4bbc23037f8a5)

Cheers!!